# Automation software with c-like scripting language

Tags: automation, autohotkey

Is there automation solution like AutoHotKey that uses a c-like language for scripting?
AutoHotKey is very useful but its syntax is strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AutoHotkey is written in C++, and is completely [open source](https://github.com/Lexikos/AutoHotkey_L).  You can mix your projects with it, although it's very disorganized.

A more realistic option is to use [AutoHotkey.dll](http://www.autohotkey.net/~HotKeyIt/AutoHotkey/files/AutoHotkey-txt.html) <sup>[direct download](http://www.autohotkey.net/~HotKeyIt/AutoHotkey.zip)</sup>.  Any languages that can use machine code DLLs, or COM (component object model).  It may include C, but it does include all of these.  (Readers: feel free to add-on).

- C++
- C#
- Java
- Python
- AutoHotkey it self

Python has a package called [AutoPy](http://www.autopy.org/)<sup>[GitHub](https://github.com/msanders/autopy/)</sup>.  It is cross-platform, and seems to have similar functionality as AutoHotkey.  I have little experience with it, though.